# Comparing Python Hashes

Tags: python, hash, md5

I want to compare a hash of my password to a hash of what the user typed in, with `(str)(hashlib.md5(pw.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())`.

The hash of the password is `b'¥_ÆMÐ1;2±*öªÝ='`. However, when I run the above code, I get `b'\xa5\x83_\xc6\x85M\xd01;2\xb1*\xf6\xaa\xdd='`.

For this reason, I can't compare these two strings. I'm looking for a function that can convert `b'\xa5\x83_\xc6\x85M\xd01;2\xb1*\xf6\xaa\xdd='` to `b'¥_ÆMÐ1;2±*öªÝ='` logically (each of the escape codes to its Unicode counterpart).

(The hash is of "lenny" if it helps. [Here](http://pastebin.com/EpsaiBts) is a link to my code.)

Comment: Please, format the question properly.

Comment: `b'¥_ÆMÐ1;2±*öªÝ='` is not a legal `bytes` object. `bytes` objects use `\x` escapes for all but printable ASCII when displaying. What you've got looks like some terrible conversion of a `str` to something that looks like `bytes` but isn't.

Comment: Something seems wrong...if you encode `'¥_ÆMÐ1;2±*öªÝ='` to `utf-8` you get `b'\xc2\xa5_\xc3\x86M\xc3\x901;2\xc2\xb1*\xc3\xb6\xc2\xaa\xc3\x9d='` which isn't the same as `b'\xa5\x83_\xc6\x85M\xd01;2\xb1*\xf6\xaa\xdd='`

Comment: @danidee try encoding everthing between this colon:b'¥ÆMÐ1;2±*öªÝ=':and that colon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.digest()` instead of `.hexdigest()` if you want the raw bytes from the hash context.

edit, line 14 from your pastebin should be:

```
if hashlib.md5(lol.encode('utf-8')).digest() == b'\xa5\x83_\xc6\x85M\xd01;2\xb1*\xf6\xaa\xdd=':
```

Comment: As a side note, it's probably also best not to use md5 (or any single hash function for that matter) for password storage for anything that matters. Use a key derivation function like pbkdf2 instead.

Comment: Can you give me the line you changed please?

Comment: This is just a side project to learn about hashing passwords, so MD5 is ok. Thanks for the info, though?